# How to bind haproxy on all interfaces except localhost without mentioning each interface separately?

Tags: haproxy

I've two hosts, host1 and host2. There's HAProxy on both hosts that is currently listening on an ip:port. This does SSL termination for a service listening at localhost:port on both hosts.

Now, we've introduced high availability, so we have a floating IP (let's call it VIP) that resides on only one of the two hosts at any given time, and the clients access the service using this floating IP instead of the one tied to the NIC.

So to continue doing successful SSL termination, we need to bind the the HAProxy on this floating vip on the node that currently owns this VIP. It'll be pretty easy to bind HAProxy on 0.0.0.0 but unfortunately, the service has to be listening on localhost on the same port as HAProxy due to things I've no control of. And I'm not in a position to change the port on which the HAProxy can listen as well.

Is there any way to configure HAProxy to listen on all hosts except localhost?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know any way to exclude a 127.0.0.1 from the wildcard * address. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14388707/122727) says

> [On Linux it's] possible to first bind a listening TCP socket to a specific IP address and port combination and later on bind another one to a wildcard IP address and the same port.

So if you start localhost-bound daemon first (lets call it httpservice) and wildcard haproxy second, everything should work as you requested.

But you need to plan what happens if httpservice dies on you. You wouldn't be able to restart it, because haproxy would block your port. To make this more admin-friendly, you would need to delete the rc.d scripts (or systemctl units) and make one shared rc.d script:

- rc.d script start action:

  ```
  if httpservice dead
      stop haproxy
      wait until nothing is bound to *:port
      start httpservice 
      wait until it binds to 127.0.0.1:port
      start haproxy
  else 
      start haproxy
  ```
- stop action:

  ```
  stop haproxy
  stop httpservice
  wait until nothing is bound to 127.0.0.1:port
  ```

Ugly as hell.

Comment: Yeah, looks like I need to change one of the ports to get this working.

Answer (score 2):

There's an [option](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#5.1-interface) for the `bind` keyword called `interface` that might do the trick, depending on your permissions (emphasis mine).

> *interface* *<interface>*
>
> Restricts the socket to a specific interface. When specified, only packets
>   received from that particular interface are processed by the socket. This is
>   currently only supported on Linux. The interface must be a primary system
>   interface, not an aliased interface. It is also possible to bind multiple
>   frontends to the same address if they are bound to different interfaces. **Note
>   that binding to a network interface requires root privileges.** This parameter
>   is only compatible with TCPv4/TCPv6 sockets.

I've never used it, but I assume it would look something like this:

```
frontend SSL-Terminator
  ...
  bind 0.0.0.0:443 ssl interface eth0
  ...
```